# Is there anything butterknife can do that databinding can't?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, butterknife

we're just starting a new project

And it seems like both butterknife and databinding are awesome tools to reduce boilerplate code.

We started with butterkife and added databinding later, the idea is to not have viewmodel classes in java instead express them in xml.

Is there any reason to keep butterkife around ?

Comment: compared to `databinding`? no, forget butterknife

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The same situation happened in my current project. We used `ButterKnife` and `DataBinding` alongside. We decided to get rid of one of those as we used `ButterKnife` version 7.X (converting to 8.X would be quite painful in such a big app). We got much cleaner code with `DataBinding` and removing the other library reduced build time :)

BUT notice that `DataBinding` still won't work with enabled `Jack&Jill` compiler, which will change soon hopefully. Using `neenbedankt-apt` and `Retrolambda` is still OK.

## **`TL;DR`**

Get rid of ButterKnife.

Answer (score 2):

`Butter Knife` come with bind resource like color, animation,...etc.

that data binding can't do actually.

Answer (score -2):

For a small XML view Data binding is good but as your view will become complex then it really hard to maintain it.
Please check the below link 
https://medium.com/@Miqubel/4-reasons-im-not-using-android-data-binding-e62127c2650c

Comment: If you are going to quote, reference the source. https://medium.com/@Miqubel/4-reasons-im-not-using-android-data-binding-e62127c2650c